# Fitting Joint Model with GLMM

Tags: r, mixed-model, survival, glmm

I'm looking to fit a joint survival model ([example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-introduction-to-joint-modeling-in-r/)). For those who are unfamiliar, joint survival models are Cox proportional hazard models where the covariates are allowed to be time-varying and are actually predictions from a mixed effects model. Typically these are fit by fitting an linear mixed effects model and survival model separately, and then putting the outputs into a joint modeling function. Example using `library(JM)` taken from [this online example](https://aurora-mareviv.github.io/talesofr/2018/02/intro-joint-modeling-r/):

```
library(JM)
# Animation example 
# Mixed-effects model fit
lmeFit.p1 <- lme(log(pro) ~ time + time:treat, data = prothro,
    random = ~ time | id)  

# Cox survival model fit
survFit.p1 <- coxph(Surv(Time, death) ~ treat, data = prothros, x = TRUE)  

# Joint model
jointFit.p1 <- jointModel(lmeFit.p1, survFit.p1, timeVar = "time",
    method = "piecewise-PH-aGH")
```

However, in the case of my particular research question, my covariates are not normally distributed (they are rates, and are therefore Poisson distributed). I assume that this means that I'll need to be using a GLMM to estimate the time-varying predictors/covariates instead of a simple LMM.

I'll be running my analyses in `R`, so am looking for packages that will accommodate GLMMs in the mixed model, but everything that I seem to find online only uses a [linear mixed effect model](https://www.annalsthoracicsurgery.org/article/S0003-4975(12)00409-2/pdf) (e.g. from `lme`).

Does anyone have any recommendations for extending the joint model to include GLMMs and/or any package recommendations to do so? I know that there are lots of GLMM packages out there that fit GLMMs, but is there anything that is analogous to the above code but using GLMMs instead of LMMs?

As an aside, I also am looking into if transformations of the covariate is appropriate. However, I'm hoping to not lose interpretability on this particular covariate.

Thank you!